# Detect whether a textbox is near the edge of the browser window

Tags: javascript

I trying to create a check in JavaScript whether a textbox is near the edge of the browser window, say 200px.

I have written a where I get the width of textbox and its offset.left and then compare to the width of the window, but I am not sure whether I am doing this correctly.

Can someone please advise me how or what is the correct way? I need to do this for both left and right positions.

```
 var textboxrightedge = $(e).width() + $(e).offset().left;
 var windowwidth = $(window).width();

 if( textboxrightedge - windowwidth > $(e).width())
 //do something
```

This is what I have written for right hand edge. I am not sure for the left, and equally I cannot get it to test if the box is in 200px. I need to check if the browser window is very small.

Comment: Yup, that's the right direction. Needs some more logic. But until we see your code, I can't tell you what logic and where it needs to go.

Comment: Show code, get answers :)  Describe issue(s) you might have.  It might also help to know the events wherein you might want to know/detect these conditions.

Comment: Just added some code

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using getboundingclient()